# JPA: The issue when deleting orphan grandchild elements

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have three classes, with each having a table:

```
Class A {
    long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    B b;
}

Class B {
    long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    C c;
}

Class C {
    long id;
}
```

There is an entry in each of tables. The link between table B and C is based on the foreign keys. If I set `A.b` as null, and then update the table for the class A, it first deletes the entry of table for class B, and then the entry of table for class C, which causes a violation exception:

```
delete from B_table where id=? [23503-176]];
```

nested exception is:

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using @JoinColumn annotation inside Class C (e.g. @JoinColumn(name="f_key_here")private B b)?

Answer (score 2):

When having such deep hierarchies you have to "chase the pointers". When you set A.b to null, JPA correctly tries to delete the B entity in the table but you get the constraint violation because it still has a reference on C. You have to also set to null B.c first and according to your setting C will be removed from the table, along with the B.c reference (FK)

The deletion of B is implicitly applied by JPA during flush; you did not call a delete  yourself so the cascade.ALL in B is not in effect. If you have a FK with cascade delete in database level then theoretically it might work but the order that the orphan removal is applied is implementation dependent and JPA does not recommend to rely on it.